# Accessing localhost WCF from other device?

Tags: c#, wcf, remote-access

I've successfully created a WCF service that works how I want it to. The only problem is that I can not access the web service from anything but the actual machine the WCF service is running.

I understand that the Cassini web service is local only, I want to be able to run the WCF service on my customers system whenever they need the service in my desktop application.

Does anyone know of an easy way to do this without the customer installing anything more than the .NET Framework?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [self-hosting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx) to host in your own app / service. If you already have the WCF service, it should be a simple matter to create a windows service and host it there (see link).

Comment: I've already been using WebServiceHost, but it doesn't seem to work for me. Accessing my system's IP:Port doesn't bring up the service page

Comment: Could be the firewall or that the user does not have sufficient privileges to host on the port you are using. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx

Comment: Can you explain the scenario I would need to take? If I'm using REST, how would I allow a remote device like my iPhone to make calls to the service, through the JS based HTML file

Comment: or is there any way to host the HTML page (website) inside the web service?

Comment: It may prevent connection to non-https services.

Answer (score 3):

WCF does not need a web server to host a service. However, something needs to be running, either a console/host application or a Windows service. Then upon startup, it can expose the service by creating an instance of the ServiceHost class. See MSDN sample at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx

Comment: See the comment that I posted in driis answer

Comment: ServiceHost, not WebServiceHost, unless your WCF service is using REST based methods (WebGet, etc)

Comment: Yes it is using REST base methods. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

To run a WCF Service, you need a host process. There is no way around that.

If the host process can (depending on whatever requirements, deployment model, network constraints, etc. apply to your case) be the same as your desktop application, then embed the service in your desktop application. This technique is called "in-proc" WCF hosting. It's basically "Self Hosting" the service in the client application. If you adopt this solution, use an IPC (net.pipe) binding as it is more optimal, and erase all potential network/firewall considerations.

If the service needs to be running on a different computer, or in a different process, then you need to use or implement a host application. IIS, WAS, AppFabric and WCFServiceHost (not a production grade host), are some examples of ready to use hosts you can use. If you cannot or do not want to use them, you will need to implement your own host application, and "Self Host" the WCF service in it. Your application can be anything: Console, Desktop, Windows Service, etc. If you don't want the users to worry about how and when to start the host, make sure it is running at all time. A windows service that starts automatically is recommended.

If the service needs to be running on a computer different from the client, then make sure that all the network devices and softwares (firewalls, routers, gateways, etc) between the server and the client are correctly configured for your binding to work. Be conscious of the protocol (http, tcp, etc) and the port (80, 443, 808, etc) your binding operates on.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the hosting step from the following article.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34668/GeoPlaces-Hybrid-smart-client-involving-RESTful-WC

In order to test your service, make a request to it and check the response. Sometimes you may not be able to download the WSDL if you haven't exposed your services metadata.

Beers!

Answer (score 0):

Here is might suggestion, if not suitable please ignore it: use a self hosted service as @driis mentioned. That is your best option for your scenario. The about hosting an HTML page inside your WCF service...yes it is possible but this is not a simple solution. To summarize in one sentence, you have to create your custom message formater and bypass the default one provided by WCF. You would create an HtmlBehavior which must inherit from WebHttpBehavior, HtmlBehaviorExtension which must inherit from BehaviorExtensionElement and  finally a HtmlFormater which would implement IDispatchMessageFormatter. On the following link you will find a great article about custom formatters: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/03/wcf-extensibility-message-formatters.aspx